# Why ksh disables stderr when subshell is executed?

Tags: shell, redirect, stdout, ksh, stderr

The program:

```
function import {
        set -x
#        read NAME < <(/usr/bin/pwd)
        NAME=$(/usr/bin/pwd)
        echo 123 >&2
        set +x
}

echo aaaaaaaaaaa
import
echo bbbbbbbbbbb
OUT=$( import 2>&1 )
echo "$OUT"
echo ccccccccccc
```

I hoped to have the output between 'aaa' and 'bbb' to be the same as in between 'bbb' and 'ccc'. But it is not the case with ksh:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa
+ /usr/bin/pwd
+ NAME=/home/neuron
+ echo 123
+ 1>& 2
123
bbbbbbbbbbb
+ /usr/bin/pwd
ccccccccccc
```

If I change $( ... ) into < <(...), stderr works as usual and I have the same output. I tried that on solaris and linux and it behaves the same, so I guess it's not ksh bug. Please note that it's not just 'set -x' being disabled, also the 'echo 123 1>&2' output disapears. In bash the code works as I would suppose.

My questions are 'why' and 'how to capture the function's stdout and stderr?'

### Thank you

Vlad

Comment: Interesting question...I'm not sure whether it is answerable other than by looking at the source code.  I can observe that `bash` behaves differently, and more nearly as you'd expect (standard error output appears), but `ksh` does not generate all the standard error output you'd expect.

Comment: This is strange.  I did notice that I do get the same output if I replace `/usr/bin/pwd` with just `pwd`.  If I change it to `/bin/pwd` I get the same result as above.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for taking a look at this. At least I know I haven't overlooked something obvious. I'm not sure I want to study ksh internals :) At the moment I'm using OUT=${ import ... } as a workaround, I just have to be cautious to declare all 'import' variables local.

Comment: Henk, I guess that's because 'pwd' is builtin, while /usr/bin/pwd calls real binary. Ksh tries to be very smart about when to do subshell and when not ...

Comment: Well, it's a bug.  See my second [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21198594/667820) below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confirmed to be a bug. And we can reproduce it very simply:

Something appears broken with nested command substitution:

```
for command in true /bin/true; do
    a=$( ( b=$( $command ); echo 123 >& 3; ) 3>& 1 ) &&
        echo a=$a command=$command
done
a=123 command=true
a= command=/bin/true
```

We run the same assignment twice, once with a builtin, and once with 
an external command.  We would expect the same results, but this fails
when we include the external command.

> Glenn Fowler:
>   I believe this was fixed between 2012-08-23 and 2012-10-12

Tested with the latest beta:

```
$ ${ksh} test.sh
Version AIJM 93v- 2014-01-14
a=123 command=true
a=123 command=/bin/true
$
$ ksh test.sh
Version JM 93u 2011-02-08
a=123 command=true
a= command=/bin/true
$
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that the ast project still has no public record for known bugs (fixed or not).

Comment: Yes, too bad there is no public repository. We found quite a lot bugs in ksh ... They are being repoted and fixed on the ksh mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in ksh (My version is `u`), and it is not specific to `pwd` or `stderr`.
Below I can reproduce the effect with `true` and fd 3.  (This allows us to keep use the shell trace)

The effect appears to be triggered by assigning output from an external process
into a variable inside a function.  If the assignment is then followed by output
to some other file descriptor, that output gets lost.

The idea here is that the `$( ... )` construct somehow conflicts with the subsequent redirect,
but only when the code in `...` is run externally.  The `true` and `pwd` builtins don't trigger a subshell in `ksh93`.

I will ask David Korn for confirmation.

```
function f1 {
    var=$( /bin/true )
    echo 123 >& 3
}

function f2 {
    var=$( true )
    echo 123 >& 3
}

function f3 {
    typeset var
    var=$( /bin/true )
    echo 123 >& 3
}

functions="f1 f2 f3"

typeset -tf ${functions} 

exec 3>& 1

echo ${.sh.version}

for f in ${functions}; do
    echo TEST $f
    functions $f
    echo "123 expected: "
    $f
    OUT=$(  $f 3>& 1  )
    echo "OUT='123' expected"
    echo "OUT='$OUT'" Captured output
    echo 
done
```

---

output:

```
Version JM 93u 2011-02-08
TEST f1
function f1 {
    var=$( /bin/true )
    echo 123 >& 3
}

123 expected: 
123
OUT='123' expected
OUT='' Captured output

TEST f2
function f2 {
    var=$( true )
    echo 123 >& 3
}

123 expected: 
123
OUT='123' expected
OUT='123' Captured output

TEST f3
function f3 {
    typeset var
    var=$( /bin/true )
    echo 123 >& 3
}

123 expected: 
123
OUT='123' expected
OUT='' Captured output
```